# Log process output to separate log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, python-multiprocessing

I have the following parallel_executor.py module which I use to run several processes simultaneously,

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class ParallelExecutor(object):
  def __init__(self, pool_size=10):
    self._pool_size = pool_size
    self._processes = []
    self._results = []

def add_task(self, target, args=None, kwargs=None):
    args = [] if not args else args
    kwargs = {} if not kwargs else kwargs
    index = len(self._processes)
    process_args = (index, target, args, kwargs)
    process = Process(target=self._executor, args=process_args)
    self._processes.append(process)
    result = {'result': None, 'end_time': 0, 'completed': False}
    self._results.append(result)
    return index

def run(self, block=True):
    if not block:
      for process in self._processes:
        process.start()
      return None
    else:
      counter = 0
      processes = []
      for process in self._processes:
        processes.append(process)
        process.start()
        if counter >= self._pool_size:

          # Wait for completion and reset counters.
          for i in range(len(processes)):
            processes[i].join()
          processes = []
          counter = 0
          continue
        counter += 1

      # Wait for the left over processes to complete.
      if len(processes) > 0:
        for i in range(len(processes)):
          processes[i].join()
      return self._results



def _executor(self, index, target, args, kwargs):
    try:
      self._results[index]['result'] = target(*args, **kwargs)
      self._results[index]['end_time'] = int(round((time.time())))
      self._results[index]['completed'] = True
    except Exception as exc:
      self._results[index]['exception'] = exc
      self._results[index]['completed'] = True
      raise
```

And I use it as follows(example.py):

```
from framework.lib.parallel_executor import ParallelExecutor
import time
import os

def foo(x):
    for i in range(3):
        print x
        time.sleep(0.5)

    return 123

def main():
    runner = ParallelExecutor()
    runner.add_task(foo, ["This"])
    runner.add_task(foo, ["is"])
    runner.add_task(foo, ["a"])
    runner.add_task(foo, ["test"])

    runner.run()
    runner.wait_for_executor_to_finish()
    for i in runner.get_results():
        print i

main()
```

My question is how do I print the process ID with every statement of 'foo' that is printed to the output by making changes only to parallel_executor.py module and not touching the example.py file, so that later I could perform a 'grep' on outputs of a particular process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without modifying the example at all, but you can achieve what you want with a very small modification.

Using the Python [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) facilities, you can set the default log message ensuring every logline will respect your standard.

In the `parallel_executor.py` add the following:

```
import logging

log_format = "%(process)d: %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=log_format)
```

In the example replace the line:

```
print x
```

with:

```
logging.info(x)
```

And you will see your messages appearing as:

```
34321: message content here
```